# Laravel 8 safe (think problem datetime-local input field to mysql)

Tags: php, laravel-8

When I click save on my form, the page reloads. Which is correct until then. Unfortunately, it does not save the data for me in the database. So I tried to find the error with `dd($request->all())`. Unfortunately, I haven't found a real error as far as the correct data is loaded on the form. However, they never end up in the database. I currently only have one guess that it is due to the wrong format of DateTime_local input. But can't say for sure.

I don't get any error messages or anything like that.

Here is a small snippet of my code:

**app/Http/Controllers/TasksController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // validate all required Data
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'user' => 'required',
        'labels' => 'required',
        'work' => 'required',
        'start_work' => 'required',
        'problems' => 'required',
        'stop_work' => 'required',
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();
    Task::create($input);

    return back()->with('success', 'Successfully saved.');
}
```

**app/Models/Task.php**

```
class Task extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $fillable = ['title', 'user', 'labels', 'work', 'start_work', 'problems', 'stop_work'];

}
```

**Migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('task', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('user');
        $table->string('label');
        $table->string('work');
        $table->string('problems');
        $table->dateTime('start_work');
        $table->dateTime('stop_work');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**View snippet**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <!-- Success message -->
    @if(Session::has('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{Session::get('success')}}
        </div>
    @endif

    <form method="post" action="{{ route('screate') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <section class="person">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Daten</h3>

                    <div class="card-tools">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="title">title</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'error' : '' }}" id="title" name="title" required>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.form-group -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username">Username</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('username') ? 'error' : '' }}" id="username" name="username">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.form-group -->
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="labels">Labels</label>
                                <select id="labels" name="label" class="select2 select2-hidden-accessible {{ $errors->has('label') ? 'error' : '' }}" multiple="" name="label[]" style="width: 100%;" data-select2-id="5" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                    @foreach($labels as $label)
                                        <option value="{{ $label->id }}">{{ $label->name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.form-group -->
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="work">work</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('work') ? 'error' : '' }}" id="work" name="work">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="start_work">Start-Work</label>
                                <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('start_work') ? 'error' : '' }}" id="start_work" name="start_work">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="problems">Problems</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('problems') ? 'error' : '' }}" id="problems" name="problems">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="stop_work">Stop-Work</label>
                                <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('start_work') ? 'error' : '' }}" id="stop_work" name="stop_work">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>

    <section class="options">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 centered">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ route('home') }}">
                    <i class="fas fa-times">
                    </i>
                    Abbrechen
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit">
                    <i class="fas fa-plus">
                    </i>
                    Speichern
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</form>
@endsection
```

I hope you can help me with this small problem.

edit:

Here is my dd output:

[dd() output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quMWJ.png)

Comment: If you suspect that it's the wrong format on your dates, then just try it with a proper format. (Mysql uses the format: `Y-m-d H:i:s`) However, we can't confirm or deny that's the issue since you haven't shown us what format you're trying to save. Add the output of `dd($request->all())` to your question. You should also check your web servers error log to see if there's any errors lying around in there.

Comment: Hello @MagnusEriksson I´ve checked my system, but I don´t find any error on my nginx-error-log. So I have no idea. I hope you can help me a little bit.

Comment: So that datetime format isn't the same as MySQL uses. Change the format before you try and save it in the database